# Error when comparing two dates

Tags: python, date, datetime

Trying to compare two dates in Python. When I run a type() check, both show up as
   `<type 'datetime.date'>`

And yet when I run a simple check against the two dates, I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Code below:

```
d_today = date.today()
oldestDate = d_today - BDay(750)
avgArray2 = [x for x in avgArray if x[0] >= oldestDate.date()]

print type(oldestDate.date())
print type(avgArray[0][0])
```

And the output:

```
<type 'datetime.date'>
<type 'datetime.date'>
avgArray2 = [x for x in avgArray if x[0].date() >= oldestDate.date()]
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Full code for how the "avgArray" is build:

```
d_today = date.today()
d_ref = d_today - BDay(66)
lastDateData = dates[0]

avgArray = []

while (d_ref >= lastDateData):
    avg_data = [x for x in stockData_sorted if (x[0] >= d_ref and x[0] <= d_ref + BDay(22))]
    avg_dates = [d[0] for d in avg_data]
    avg_graphData = [d[1] for d in avg_data]

    workingAvg = sum(avg_graphData)/len(avg_graphData)
    avgArray.append((d_today,workingAvg))

    d_today = d_today - BDay(1)
    d_ref = d_ref - BDay(1)
```

Comment: What is the result of `print([type(x[0]) for x in avgArray])`?

Comment: Here's the output - <class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'> - That's why I was using the ".date()" call to convert to a datetime date (or so I thought)

Comment: What's the `avgArray` consists ? can you give the code where this array was built?

Comment: It's a database pull from a PSQL database. The two fields it pulls and their database coding are:date (timestamp) and dispersion (numeric). I added the full code in the original post for how the avgArray is built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'` not a normal datetime object; which does not have a `.date()` method.

```
 avgArray2 = [x for x in avgArray
              if datetime.date(x[0].year, x[0].month, x[0].day) >= oldestDate.date()]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't realize it didn't have the date() method. Although now I'm getting this error: TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

Comment: Finally got this working. Simple mistake that I should have realized awhile ago - just had to call the function as: date(x[0].year, x[0].month, x[0].day). Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have two instances of `datetime.date`, as per your output:

```
<type 'datetime.date'>
<type 'datetime.date'>
```

then the error is calling a non-existent `date` method on each -- they're already dates, just compare them directly.

IOW, in lieu of

```
if x[0].date() >= oldestDate.date()
```

just

```
if x[0] >= oldestDate
```

should work fine.

Added: it seems that despite the misleading output `x[0]` is **not** a `datetime.date` but rather a pandas timestamp (I'm unable in this case to explain the output).  If that's the case,

```
datetime.date(x[0].year, x[0].month, x[0].day) >= oldestDate
```

might work better.

Comment: That's what's confusing to me. When I run the code like you suggest I get the following error:     avgArray2 = [x for x in avgArray if x[0] >= oldestDate]
  File "tslib.pyx", line 694, in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__richcmp__ (pandas/tslib.c:12256)
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'

Comment: Editing the A to mention this anomaly.